# Trying to write a hartree fock program; confused about potential energy integral

Tags: physical-chemistry, integration, quantum-chemistry

The book I am working from has the following
$$
{V}_{ij} = \int dr_1 Φ^*_i  Σ_a\frac{Z_a}{r_1 - R_a} Φ_j
$$

This is for the nuclear-electron attraction.

Let's look at a simple case: a hydrogen atom. In this case there is only one nucleus and one electron, so we don't need the sum, and $Z_a$ is just 1.

This makes the equation into:

$$
{V}_{ij} = \int dr_1 Φ^*_i  \frac{1}{r_1 - R_a} Φ_j
$$

I'm using gaussian functions (which is to say, $c*e^{-zr^2}$ type functions) as my Φ's.

But let's look at the integral: two gaussians times another gaussian is yet another gaussian. The gaussians I use are fully real, so the order/complex conjugate does nothing. So I can re-order the integral into:

$$
{V}_{ij} = \int dr_1   \frac{1}{r_1 - R_a} Φ_iΦ_j
$$

And since the two gaussians give me another gaussian, it becomes something like this:

$$
{V}_{ij} = \int dr_1   \frac{1}{r_1 - R_a}c*e^{-zr^2}
$$
The problem I am running in to is that an integrand of the type $\frac{c*e^{-zr^2}}{r}$ does not converge on what I assume the limits are supposed to be (0 to infinity). I am assuming that the r in the exponential and the r in the fraction both refer to $r_1$, i.e., the same variable of integration.

I think I have set something up wrong, but I am not sure what. Do I have the limits of integration wrong? Is $R_a$ a constant? What is it even referring to? I think it's supposed to be the coordinates of nucleus A in the coordinate space I am using. In this case, I am just using one nucleus, so would it be wrong to say $R_a$ is 0 since I can put it at the center of my space? Even if it's not 0, if it's another constant distance, the integral still won't converge if $r_1 - R_a$ is in the limits of integration... are r in the gaussian exponent and r in the fraction the same variable?

I'm doing this for quantum chemistry purposes, but I think I"d get better help on the physics board for this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a notation issue. This is an integral over all three-dimensional space, not one dimension. Your second line would normally look something like 
$$
V_{ij}(\vec R_a) = \int d\vec r_1 \Phi_i^*(\vec r_1) \frac{1}{|\vec r_1 - \vec R_a|} \Phi_j(\vec r_1)~.
$$
Now when you express this in spherical coordinates ($r_1, \theta, \phi)$, you have to include the Jacobian in writing the integral. Recall,
$$
\int_{\rm{all~space}} d\vec r_1  \to \int_0^\infty dr_1 r_1^2 \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \sin\theta \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi
$$
The extra factors of $|\vec r_1|$ from the Jacobian will allow the integrand to converge for all $\vec r_1$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thanks. I assume I would need to use the jacobian to calculate other integrals, like the overlap integral as well?

Comment: The Jacobian is necessary anytime you want to integrate using non-Cartesian ($x,y,z$) coordinates. If you're using Gaussian wavefunctions, then spherical coordinates may be a good choice.